# keystone fails to authenticate any service on openstack

Tags: authentication, keystone

Not able to run any command that requires authentication from keystone, including logging in horizon. Every command fails with below error:

## **keystone user-list**

**Authorization Failed:** An unexpected error prevented the server from fulfilling your request. (OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'keystone_admin'@'controllerip' (using password: YES)") None None (HTTP 500)

Answer (score 0):

Please look into keystone log first and see what's the issue brought HTTP 500.

Answer (score 0):

Your keystone database Credentials(user-keystone_admin) may be wrong.Try changing them with the actual  database credentials in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf file.

```
[sql]

connection = mysql://<username>:<password>@<ip>/keystone
```